# How to encourage reuse of 3D models in a team of 3D artists?

Tags: 3d-modeling, asset-workflow

What would be a pipeline that would help our team reuse 3D models/assets?

We've got 10 3D artists that create game characters and we want to facilitate discovery and encourage reuse of 3D assets.

Good communication could be a key; what other approaches would help us?

Comment: I edited out the software resquest part because asking for software is off-topic here.

Comment: Could you provide more context about the content your artists are creating? 2d vs 3d? Look up kit bashing and modular design.

Comment: 3d characters models